how to make sure that clerk auth's useUser() does not return null
I am trying to fetch data from my database when a /GET is made to the /home page
the issue i face is, when i use the clerk auth's useUser() hook and call user.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress inside my useEffect it returns null. if i do it without a useEffect you can see the expected behaviour (but there are constant calls being made to the api)
how do i make sure that useUser() does not return null
here's necessary code snippets
this is within the useEffect() get a null response for user here
export default function Page() {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
  const { user } = useUser();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        if (user) {
          const response = await fetch("/api/get-quotes/for-home", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              creator: user.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress,
            }),
          });
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Failed to fetch quotes");
          }
          const data = await response.json();
          setQuotes(data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching quotes:", error);
      }
    };
  },[])

  return(<>{jsx}</>);
}

this is without a useEffect(), works as expected but keeps making constant calls to the database
export default function Page() {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
  const { user } = useUser();

  // Function to fetch data
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      if (user) {
        const response = await fetch("/api/get-quotes/for-home", {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            creator: user.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress,
          }),
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Failed to fetch quotes");
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        setQuotes(data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching quotes:", error);
    }
  };

  // Call fetchData immediately when the component is first rendered
  fetchData();
  
  return(<>{jsx}</>);

}

